# Run php alphabetic index on click

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make an alphabetic index of content in a mysql database.

the second part is not my problem, what I have code is the buttons, and, when pressing o one of the letter buttons, run a mysql query with the letter.

I have coded a form for every letter like this:

```
<form action="query.php?x=A" method="get">
       <input type=submit value="A">
</form>
```

changing `"A"` with every letter.

then in `query.php` I have a `$_get["x"]` and with it I run the query.

so, I have 27 forms, but that is very dirty, is there any other way to write it?

and, if its possible, is there any way to run the mysql query in the same page? (to be able to run another letter.)

Comment: Example code added to show how to test and use it.

Comment: Since you are using GET anyway, you don’t need to use a form, you can use simple _links_ with a parameter in the URL, something like `query.php?letter=A`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple and a little crude but it works...

The idea is to have 26 submit buttons with a different letter value in each.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['theLetter'])) {

    if (    ctype_alpha($_GET['theLetter'])
         && strlen($_GET['theLetter']) === 1) {

        $theLetter = $_GET['theLetter'];

        echo '<br />', 'A valid letter of: ', $theLetter, ' was input.';
    }
    else {
        echo '<br />', 'Incorrect input: ', htmlentities($_GET['theLetter']), ' was input.';
    }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
  <meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
  <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="" method="get">

      <?php  $letter =  ORD('a'); ?>
      <?php  while ($letter <= ORD('z')): ?>
            <input type="submit" name="theLetter"  value="<?= CHR($letter) ?>">
            <?php $letter++; ?>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: And how can i use the letter which has been "pressed"?  a simple code, like "the letter pressed is: ..." thanks

Answer (score -1):

you can try this code

```
<form action="query.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="letter" />
   <input type=submit>
```

in your query.php add $_POST['letter'] instead od $_GET['X']

Comment: hmmm that its very messing... do you know if is there a way to put 27 input buttons, then "know" which button was pressed and then pass that to the action?

Comment: you should fill one alphabetic on input text with name letter